# Session Logout in every two minutes

Tags: asp.net

I have Web Application in asp.net.
Where I am maintaining Session for every User. And every Time I got logout in Approx 2 min.
I tried to increase this time through web Config File upto 60 min but it is not working For me and I m getting same problem.

I have created A class file For maintaining session.I am Using This Code.

```
public static void createSession(System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState session)
    {
        Session = session;

    }
```

This is my class file code.

And I am calling this function in login Page load like this.

```
BusinessClasses.SessionHandler.createSession(Page.Session);
```

Then After I am Checking In everyPage.

But this code is not working for me.
Please Give Suggest me correct solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function of yours is doing nothing, just assigning a variable to itself. Anyway, as they told you, you should delete this function and use the built-in asp .net session management.

Try to change the web.config to something like:

```
   <sessionState timeout="99999">
   </sessionState>
```

It should work.

Answer (score 4):

Hard to tell from what you've posted, but what are you doing maintaining sessions down in your business layer when ASP.NET does it for you in the web layer where it belongs?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing createsesion() and access the session as

```
HttpContext.Current.Session
```

Answer (score 1):

Session can be reset if the App pool running the app has terminated. Make sure there are no events in the Eventlog from the web server saying the pool was terminated and had to be restarted.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the Session.Timeout value that can be set.